# How to get class of an image that I found earlier using its xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So, I found the image using it's xpath

```
image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id=\'image\']')
```

and I need to check if it has the class of "thatOneImage"

How?

using selenium and python

Comment: So check it's class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_attribute()` to get class attribute of `image` and check if the attribute value is the expected class :

```
image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="image"]')
classToCheck = "thatOneImage"

#check if image has class thatOneImage
isHasTheClass = classToCheck in image.get_attribute('class')
```

If `image` can have compound class, you may want to split it to individual classes first :

```
image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="image"]')
classToCheck = "thatOneImage"

#split compound class into individual classes 
classes = image.get_attribute('class').split(' ')
#check if 'thatOneImage' is one of the class image has
isHasTheClass = classToCheck in classes
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If you `split` a string by `' '` it will return a list of strings and in that case will `in` work as intended?

Comment: @Saifur yup. Though the meaning of `in` as in the 2nd example is slightly different from `in` in the 1st example. `'test' in ['test', 'foo', 'bar']` return `True`, that the expected behavior right?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the class attribute of any `WebElement` and do a quick string search shown as follows:

```
image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id=\'image\']')

attr = image.get_attribute('class')

if 'thatOneImage' in attr:
  print "Class found"
```